# Delphi Indy IPsec support

Tags: security, delphi, indy

I've been using `TIdTCPClient` for sending data to a server, sometimes using SSL, and now I have the task to do it using IPsec.

I found some classes like `TIdTunnelMaster` and `TIdTunnelSlave`, but without obvious connection to other parts of the library.

Is there a proper approach to integrate IPsec to Indy packets? Or is that just impossible and should be done without Indy at all?

Current method:

```
procedure SendData;
var
  idClient: TidTCPClient;
  indySSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  indySSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  indySSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  idClient := TidTCPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    idClient.Host := 'localhost';
    idClient.Port := 1111;
    idClient.IOHandler := indySSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    idClient.Connect;
    idClient.IOHandler.Write(12345);
    idClient.Disconnect;
  finally
    idClient.Free;
    indySSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Indy does not have any direct support for IPsec. The Tunnel components you mention have nothing to do with that. AFAIK, IPsec is handled at the OS's internal networking layers, not at the application layer. Apps communicate with the TCP stack normally, and the TCP stack will deal with IPsec as needed per OS configuration.

Comment: @Lebeau Ok thanks, so it's actually not my task at all and the question should be closed.

Comment: Try asking on [su] or [sf] instead.

Comment: Please note that the provided code is buggy since it doesn't protect the objects using `try..finally` blocks.

Comment: @Andreas True, modified it as needed.

Comment: @Lebeau No need, the customer corrected his request, it's definitely not my task, I just wasn't aware of IPsec and what it is for.